# SharePoint List To and From date/time not within and existing entries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, validation

I'm creating a car booking system. The idea is that individuals can book from 3 pool cars.

I've created a list with a from and to Date and Time. I want to prevent the user selecting an existing booked period for a specific car. 
Ideally, I need to do this in the form so it cannot get submitted if a clash occurs. Can Column Validation help here?